# Not finitely generated homology covered by finitely generated homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, finitely-generated

I want to

> Find a space X which is covered by finitely many open sets $U_i$ such that $H_n(U_i)$ is finitely generated for all n but $H_n(X)$ is not finitely generated.

I know how to produce Moore spaces for finitely generated Abelian groups and the first guess of not fg group that comes to mind is $\mathbb Q$. But I can't really produce spaces with homnology $\mathbb Q$.

Any help?

Comment: Hint: for me, the first group that comes to mind is an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I thought of that. But I can't seem to cover it with finitely many open sets with fg Homology groups. Can you help me out?

Comment: Have you noticed that $S^1$ is a union of two contractible open sets, and that so is $\bigvee_\mathbb{N}S^1$?

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the problem. Take X = infinite wedge of circles (wedging not done at a single point,rather take lateral wedging). Then A = all the circles minus the north poles. B = all the circles minus the south poles.